# Which Android device has no FEATURE_TELEPHONY

Tags: android-studio

I am aware that we can check `FEATURE_TELEPHONY` with `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature`. However, I didn't come across any Android simulator that fail this check. Does anyone know which Android device has no `FEATURE_TELEPHONY`?

Comment: Consider e.g. a tablet without a SIM card slot.

Comment: Yea but there doesn't seem to have this kind of tablet on Android Studio AVD

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your emulator extended controls where you will find cellular then you can set the signal strength and type and some other parameters. my guess it'll work, let me know anyway!

Comment: Nope, doesn't work haha